# Jackson Deserialization with no Type

Tags: kotlin, jackson, deserialization

I have a question related to Jackson and polymorphism: is there a way to deserialize a JSON string without specifying a type?

Assuming I don't own this message (e.g., external API) and I have two separate messages that come in at separate times:

```
{
    "responseCode": 200
    "responseMessage": "You did something successfully"
}

{
    "errorCode": 401
    "errorDescription": "Permission denied"
}
```

And I want to deserialize this message with some data classes that I created based on these messages through polymorphism (see abstract class in next code block):

```
data class MyDataClass(
    val responseCode: Int,
    val responseMessage: String
): MyAbstractClass()

data class MyOtherDataClass(
    val errorCode: Int,
    val errorDescription: String
): MyAbstractClass()
```

And I am resolving these messages through a function that will use the Jackson Object Mapper to deserialize the stringified JSON payload:

```
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyDataClass::class),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyOtherDataClass::class)
)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreProperties = true)
abstract class MyAbstractClass

fun receiveMessage(message: String) {
    val convertedMessage = jacksonObjectMapper().readValue<MyAbstractClass>(message)

    log.info(convertedMessage)
    /* prints either:
    MyDataClass(responseCode=200, responseMessage=You did something successfully)
    OR
    MyOtherDataClass(errorCode=401, errorDescription=Permission denied)
    */
}
```

But since I haven't described how to identify the data class (using `@JsonTypeInfo`), it fails.

To repeat, I am curious if there is a way that I can deserialize the incoming message to one of my polymorphic types without having to specify the `@JsonTypeInfo`. Or if I must describe the `@JsonTypeInfo`, how would I do this with no similarities between the two child classes of `MyAbstractClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a custom deserializer which takes it as a generic `JSONObject` or the like. Then I'd check if a differentiating key exists. For example:

```
// pseudocode
when (json: JSONObject) {
    hasKey("responseCode") -> // deserialize as MyDataClass
    hasKey("errorCode") -> // deserialize as MyOtherDataClass
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I suppose I am coming from a naive viewpoint as well. Since Kotlin is strongly typed, I shouldn't expect to have Jackson pick up my data classes automatically.

Comment: In addition, I guess with `receiveMessage(jsonObject: JSONObject)` would be the parameter and then use your `when` statement. This would eliminate the use case of the `abstract class MyAbstractClass` with the annotations, right?

Comment: Correct, `MyAbstractClass` would no longer be used.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help.